# ignoring years while parse a date using moment.js

Tags: momentjs

I am new to moment.js

I am trying to format a date using moment.js

my date string is

```
var myDate = '2014-05-01T00:00:00.000+0530';

var newDate = moment(myDate , 'yyyy-MM-dd"T"HH:mm:ss.fffffff"Z"').toDate()
```

console.log(newDate) gives

```
 Date {Mon May 01 0000 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)}
```

Please help me get the year part.

Comment: Not sure if moment.js is case sensitive, but the doc relates that Year is YYYY

Comment: Great ! I post it as an anwser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if moment.js is case sensitive, but the doc relates that Year is YYYY